# transforming data frame in ipython a little like transpose

Tags: pandas, ipython

Suppose I have a data frame like the following data.frame in pandas

```
 a   1  11
 a   3  12
 a  20  13
 b   2  14
 b   4  15
```

I want to generate a resulting data.frame like this

```
  V1  1  2  3  4 20
   a 11 NaN 12 NaN 13
   b NaN 14 NaN 15 NaN
```

How can I get this transformation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','a','a','b','b'],
                   'col2': [1,3,20,2,4],
                   'col3': [11,12,13,14,15]})
print df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2')
```

Output:

```
     col3                
col2   1   2   3   4   20
col1                     
a      11 NaN  12 NaN  13
b     NaN  14 NaN  15 NaN
```